# UTF-8 encoding error

Tags: article

Good afternoon, there was an error with UTF-8 encoding, I use the following preamble.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
    \usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
    \usepackage[left=25mm, top=20mm, right=15mm, bottom=20mm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[russian]{babel}
    \usepackage{tempora} %Times New Roman alike                                     
    \usepackage{newtxmath} %Times New Roman in math
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    %работа с файлом%
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    %работа с таб
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{emdash}{\textemdash}
    \captionsetup[figure]{name={Рисунок},labelsep=emdash}   
    \captionsetup[table]{name={Таблица},labelsep=emdash}   
    \newwrite\tempfile
    \usepackage{float}
    \linespread{1.5}
    \setlength{\parindent}{5ex}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \graphicspath{{pictures/E:\mtotv}}
```

What I don't understand in another file, everything works correctly without errors with the same preamble, I use the same thing in both files, I tried to create a new file did not help.
Here is the error log file https://pastebin.com/PS9QAM2f

Comment: posting the preamble does not help anyone debug the error, you should post a small example that shows the error, however the error is `The document does not appear to be in UTF-8 encoding.`  possibly you have accidentally saved the file in a legacy 8 bit encoding. Any code posted to this site is always utf-8 so it may not be possible  to show that here. Checj your editor is saving files in UTF-8

Comment: Off-topic: Instead `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}` and `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}`, please write `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` and `\counterwithin{equation}{section}`.